# How to iteratively fill a matrix with rnorm values using a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, normal-distribution

I have a question, I am trying to create a 10x10 matrix using the code below, where the first column contains 10 values from a normal distribution with std dev of .5 and a mean equal to j where j is a value 1:10. My code below produces the observed matrix, where only the final column is filled with values. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

```
      for(j in 1:10){
      y<-matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10)
        y[,j]<-rnorm(n=10,mean=j,sd=.5)
}


      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]     [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 10.857520
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 10.490549
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  9.888620
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  9.495205
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  9.674356
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 10.810197
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 10.337517
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  9.715229
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  9.902603
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0  8.972656
```

Comment: `y<-matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=10)
for(j in 1:10){
    y[,j]<-rnorm(n=10,mean=j,sd=.5)
 }` is okay. You should create an empty matrix outside the loop.

Comment: Also: `sapply(1:10, function(x) rnorm(10, mean=x, sd=0.5) )`

Comment: Thank you very much! If I may ask, why does creating the empty matrix within the for loop not result in the desired answer?

Comment: @slwu89 - because at the last step, where `j` is `10`, you create a brand new matrix full of `0`'s, and then fill the `j`th , or `10`th column.